# Github showing zero contributors

Tags: github

I have recently created a repo for my team and we have 12 commits by 3 different people, yet it is still showing 0 contributors. Also, when I view the individual commits, I can't click on any of the users.

[image]

What can be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused when people commit under their full name and not their github username. Ask your members to set their git config properly
by running the following in a terminal:

```
git config --global user.name "your-github-username"
git config --global user.email "your-github-email"
```

After this is done all future commits will be linked to the github username, you will be able to click and be directed to the github user profiles and contributors will also properly be displayed.